# django rest framework -- redirect to login with next parameter if authentication fails

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I use a Django Rest Framework (v2.3.8) `APIView` to redirect to a login page with the `next` url parameter set when a User accesses a page without proper authentication?

Comment: Are you using DRF as a front-end client as well?  Or are you using a different technology for your front-end client?

Comment: @RossRogers well I may not understand your question correctly, but this is a class-based DRF APIView.  Users can `GET` the view to see some data or they can `POST` to the view with an API token in the header to update some related data.

Answer (score 4):

I'm completely sure that Matt has realized by now how to do this, but for anyone new checking this question, you can use the the same methods that you would use for any other django view. Note: this answer is using django 1.11 urls, for django 2+ urls you should check django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example).

1. using the `login_required` decorator

   ```
   # urls.py

   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
   from myapp import views

   urlpatterns += [
       url(r'^my-url/', login_required(views.MyView.as_view()), name='my-name'),
   ]
   ```
2. using the `LoginRequired` mixin

   ```
   # views.py

   from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

   class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, APIView):
       ...

   # urls.py

   from myapp import views

   urlpatterns += [
       url(r'^my-url/', views.MyView.as_view(), name='my-name'),
   ]
   ```

More details and examples can be found at django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like that?

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
urlpatterns = [
    path('swagger/', login_required(schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0)), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
]
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-10">
         {{ form.as_p }}
         {% if redirect_field_value %}
         <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
         {% endif %}
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use DRF's built-in login and logout views/templates, you add `rest_framework.urls` to your top-level `urls.py` file like so:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

Assuming you have `rest_framework` installed, this accesses its `urls.py` file and adds the rest_framework namespace. If you dig into it, `rest_framework.urls` actually looks very similar to any other `urls.py` pattern - it just links up the `rest_framework` templates with Django's built-in login and logout views:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views

template_name = {'template_name': 'rest_framework/login.html'}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, template_name, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, template_name, name='logout'),
]
```

The `rest_framework` default templates work like any other login - it sends POSTs requests with `username` and `password` fields to `api-auth/login` to validate against your User database (assuming you're using Django's auth.User model). You can also create your own login template (which will do the same thing). Instead of changing the DRF files, what I'd do is mashup the code so my top-level urls.py file looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views

template_name = {'template_name': 'custom_login.html'}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-auth/login/$', views.login, template_name, name='login'),
    url(r'^api-auth/logout/$', views.logout, template_name, name='logout'),
]
```

It still uses Django's built-in login and logout views, but your own template. Hope this helps!

Comment: Does not answer the question, rather just describes how to perform login.